# Formating Excel Worksheet from a different workbook's VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Multiple Excel files (Copying information from a master file into smaller more specific files for reporting) and am having trouble getting my master file to format the area files while it is putting information in them. Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim I_workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set I_workbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("H:\....")
Set ws = I_workbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'... Enter information into the ws. 
      'This part works so I know I have proper objects and such



Dim rng As Range
For Each rng In ws.Range("B2", "B" & (BotRow - TopRow + 2))
        rng.Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        'rng.NumberFormat = "General"
Next rng

I_workbook.Save
xl.Quit
```

I am trying to take all the cells that I have put information into and format them as a number. Somtimes they are numbers and sonetimes they are numbers followed by a letter. Their source is a text field in a database so excel reads them as text and then puts a nice annoying green triangle in the corner that annoys someone high up so here I sit...

The commented line `rng.NumberFormat = "General"` is another attempt of mine that did not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rng.Numberformat` should work unless there's more to the story, but you don't actually need to loop to do that:

```
ws.Range("B2", "B" & (BotRow - TopRow + 2)).Numberformat = "General"
```

will suffice. If the data in the cells is numbers stored as text, you can use something like this:

```
With ws.Range("B2", "B" & (BotRow - TopRow + 2))
   .Numberformat = "General"
   .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```

Comment: No dice. `ws.Range("B2", "B" & (BotRow - TopRow + 2)).NumberFormat = "General"` Could it have to do with it being pasted in there from a database link? When I open it I can do it manually using the formatting warning but it doesnt fix it using right click -> format cells -> number -> general. I feel like if anything that way should work. I tried recording a macro when i did it using the green triangle warning but got nothing. Thanks

Comment: The code will change the cell format. If it doesn't change the displayed data in the cell, that's a completely different thing - it means you have text. See my edit.

Comment: That did it, Thank you. Why does changing the value allow for a reformat?

Comment: It's like selecting the cell, pressing f2 then Enter, which usually gets Excel to reinterpret the data as necessary, assuming the cell format isn't Text.